# SVN commit failure in eclipse/ADT

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, adt, subversion-edge

I am new to using SVN, and I am trying it out on an android project. I am getting a commit failure based on this error..

```
svn: E155023: Can't set properties on 'C:\AndroidWorkSpace\myApp\bin\res': invalid status for updating properties.
```

I have searched for similar problems, but the lingo is all over my head. I just installed SVN on eclipse (it has successfully updated/committed previously), and I opened a repository on cloudforge.com. Other than that, I don't know much about it.

I have tried cleaning project and running team>clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the description of the bug, which might cause this error:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4004

Hope that helps!